# Apache Airflow - how many tasks in a DAG is too many?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, orchestration, airflow

I tried having a DAG with 400 tasks (like each one running calling remote spark server to process a separate data file into s3...nothing to do with mysql) and airflow (v1.10.3) did the following for the next 15mins:

- cpu stayed at 99%
- did not handle new putty login or ssh requests to
  my machine (amazon linux)
- airflow webserver stopped responding..only
  gave 504 errors
- Started 130 concurrent connections to mysql RDS
  (airflow metadb)
- kept my tasks stuck in scheduled state

i eventually switched to another ec2 instance but got same outcome...

I am running LocalExecutor on single machine (16 CPUs).

Note for a DAG with 30 tasks it runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no actual limit to the number of tasks in a DAG. In your case, you're using `LocalExecutor` - airflow will then use any resources available on the host to execute the tasks. It sounds like you just overwhelmed your ec2 instance's resources and overloaded the airflow worker(s) / scheduler. I'd recommend adding more workers to break up the tasks or lowering the `parallelism` value in your airflow.cfg